# currentUser is AuthContext.js gives something, but when exported is shows undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is AuthContext.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { auth } from '../firebase';

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

function signup(email, password) {
    return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
}
function login(email, password) {
    return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
}
function logout() {
    return auth.signOut();
}

useEffect(() => {
    const unsuscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        setCurrentUser(user);
        setLoading(false);
        console.log(user, 'user'); // This gives an object
    });

    return unsuscribe;
}, []);

console.log(currentUser, 'cU1');
const value = {
    currentUser,
    signup,
    login,
    logout,
};

return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
        {!loading && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
);};
```

This is Header.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Nav, Navbar, Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth } from '../contexts/AuthContext';

export const Header = () => {
   const [error, setError] = useState('');
   const { logout, currentUser } = useAuth();

const history = useHistory();
const myStyle = {
    zIndex: 200,
};

//console.log(currentUser, 'cU');

async function handleLogout() {
    setError('');
    try {
        await logout();
        history.push('/login');
    } catch {
        setError('Failed to logout');
    }
}

return (
    <div className='Header'>
        {error && <Alert variant='danger'>{error}</Alert>}
        <Navbar bg='dark' variant='dark' expand='lg' style={myStyle}>
            <Link to='/'>
                <Navbar.Brand>Photo-Terrace</Navbar.Brand>
            </Link>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='basic-navbar-nav' />
            <Navbar.Collapse id='basic-navbar-nav'>
                <Nav className='ml-auto mr-auto'>
                    <Link to='/'>
                        <Nav.Link href='#home'>Go to Your Photos</Nav.Link>
                    </Link>
                </Nav>
                <Nav className=' mr-100'>
                    <Link to='/signup'>
                        <Nav.Link href='#home'> Sign Up</Nav.Link>
                    </Link>
                    <Link to='/login'>
                        <Nav.Link href='#home'>Log In</Nav.Link>
                    </Link>
                    <Link to='/update-profile'>
                        <Nav.Link href='#home'>Update Profile</Nav.Link>
                    </Link>
                    <Link to='/'>
                        <Nav.Link href='#home' onClick={handleLogout}>
                            Log Out
                        </Nav.Link>
                    </Link>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    </div>
);};
```

When I try to give setCurrentUser(user.email) in useEffect in AuthContext.js, it gives the email when console logged. But when it's just setCurrentUser(user), it shows undefined.
Moreover, when it is exported, signup,login give some value, but currentUser shows undefined when console logged in Header.js.
The problem is, how should I get value of currentUser in Header.js
It also shows error of

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'logout' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is 
undefined.
```

because of this

```
const { logout, currentUser } = useAuth();
```

Comment: Share this code in codesanbox.io and I will help you out there.

Also currentUser is set asynchronously and so you can always keep a check like so in Header JSX,
 {currentUser && <h1> {currentUser.email}</h1>}
The other error for 'logout' though is strange. Probably something isn't getting exported or imported the right way.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user), you should check, within the [`onAuthStateChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged) observer, that the `user` object is not `null`.

As matter of fact, depending on the sign-in/login flow it may happen that the first time the `onAuthStateChanged()` observer is triggered the user is `null` because he/she is not signed-in.

```
const unsuscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
       setCurrentUser(user);
       setLoading(false);
       console.log(user, 'user'); // This gives an object
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried signing in and then console logged currentUser, still undefined. Can you tell me why this error exists:
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'logout' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is 
undefined.